# Direction Coupler

Tags: rf

While testing a direction coupler (i am testing 30 dB DC ), I found that when I am giving signal at port 1 and output at port 2 (through port), it provides insertion loss and at coupled port its providing copuled loss of 30dB which is normal expected operation. But the main problem i am facing is when i am giving signal through coupled port and measure at output the expected signal is 30db less but i am getting this expected result only when i keep the port 1 open. When i terminate port one, then the signal is -55db. Even when i give input to port 2 and measure the coupled port, only when i keep port on open i am getting expected of -30 dB result else the output is -55dB. Why does this happen. isn't a coupler a reciprocal device?

Answer (score 3):

The coupling of -30 dB is between port 1 and the coupled port (P4 in the figure below). The "coupling" between ports P1 and P3 is called actually called *isolation*. Ideally, the isolation is infite = so the coupling between P1 and P3 is -infinity dBm.

[image]

> But the main problem i am facing is when i am giving signal through coupled port and measure at output the expected signal is 30db less

Thats because you are actually measuring the isolation.

> but i am getting this expected result only when i keep the port 1 open.

Thats because the signal is going from the coupled port (P4) to the input (P1) and is reflected to P2, because P1 is open and thus the power is reflected.

> When i terminate port one, then the signal is -55db.

Your are measuring between port 2 and coupled port. You are now measuring the isolation, which is -infinite dB for an ideal DC.

You should always termimate all ports in RF devices with the characteristic impedance, which is almost always 50 ohms.

[image]

The dashed line representes the leaking signal. Ideally theres none = infinite isolation. You're measusing an isolation of 55 dBs.

Answer (score 0):

Why? what does the datasheet say about the freq. you tested? Yes it is reciprocal.

When ∑ port is terminated isolation between ports 1 and 2 are ~30 dB
Loss between ∑ port is 3.5dB to both ports 1 and 2 unless one port is open then it reduces to 0.5dB on the other port in both directions.

Comment: Its a 1GHz coupler. when i terminate the sum port, why does it affect so much? shouldn't it be showing -30dB?

Comment: Try sweeping it. Your asumptions on something may be invalid, cable etc